# What are Java Interfaces used for? (multiple choice question)

Tags: java, object-oriented, interfaces

I'm a beginner studying interfaces in Java through some quizzes and I came through this question:

> What are Java Interface used for?

I can opt among one of the following three choices:

> A. They're used to describe the API of various classes.
>
> B. They're used to avoid having to specify the contract for methods.
>
> C. They're used to let real and apparent types differ. You can obtain this difference only by using interfaces.

I think the right answer is Choice A. Choice B doesn't make sense to me, since Interfaces usually describe methods along with their contract. Choice C doesn't make sense either, but I might be wrong.

Which one is the right answer? Thank you!

Comment: The first answer is heading into tautology territory, but the other two are factually incorrect. I'm not sure you'll learn anything from such a quiz

Comment: @Caleth You don't learn from quizzes. You check your understanding. One way to do this is to write a tautology (or rather, the same thing in different terms) and see if the reader can tell this. This is obviously a quiz for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A. They're used to describe the API of various classes.

Correct.

I struggle with the correctness of the phrasing. It's not wrong, but it is essentially a confusing tautology. But they had to avoid calling it "the interface" to not give away the answer, and I'm struggling to find a better (and similarly terse) alternative.

> B. They're used to avoid having to specify the contract for methods.

Quite the opposite, the interface **is** the contract.

> C. They're used to let real and apparent types differ. You can obtain this difference only by using interfaces.

The first part of the statement is correct, and is basically describing polymorphism.

The second part of the statement is incorrect, since polymorphism also applies to inheritance.

Comment: That's the problem with a Java-esque `interface` being a specific severely restricted and anemic attempt at capturing the distorted reflection of what an *interface* is.

Comment: polymorphism also applies to classes at the end surely?

Comment: @jk. Not sure what you mean with "classes at the end". It applies to relations (i.e. interface + its implementation, or base class + derived class) rather than to a single class.

Comment: I meant that class inheritance is the specific example of polymorphism happening not through interfaces

Comment: @jk.: Unless I'm misunderstanding your, that is exactly what the last sentence of my answer conveys.

Comment: inheritance also applies to interfaces, you are not *explicitly* pointing out it can also apply to classes, the fact that it applies to classes is the bit that makes the last statement false